# Inline-block, floats or other solution to make squares line up with edge of input on both sides

Tags: css-float, css

I am creating a page with an input box at the top and rows of three squares underneath. It is a shopping list app and as you add items in the input box, it will create a new square.

I want to line up the left edge of square 1 with the left edge of the input box and the right edge of square 3 with the right edge of the input box and have the middle square centered in between.

Here is a mock-up:

[image: https://plus.google.com/photos/109467108828976645259/albums/6018459118106541745?authkey=CLH-k9HPoe6__gE]

What is the best way to do this?

I've tried display:inline-block for the squares, but I can't get the positioning correct so that the outermost squares line up with the edges of the input box and the middle one is centered. Giving the squares a left-margin of 5% and then removing the left margin from the first square seemed to get close, but it is off in Safari.

I also tried using floats, but I needed to rearrange the order of my list, so that it went: square 1, square 3, square 2. Square 1 was floated to the left and square 2 was floated to the right. This messed up the pink background color that I had assigned to every odd list item. It also required that I insert empty divs to clear the floats for each row.

What is the best solution to get the square edges lined up with the edges of in the input box and have the middle one be centered in between?

HTML:

```
    <div class="wrapper">

    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="I need to buy..." name="shopping_item" class="shopping_item">
    </form>
    <ul class="instructions">
        <li>Double-click square to edit</li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li>Click and drag square to rearrange</li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li>Click on text to cross off</li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li>Hover and click “Delete” to delete</li>
    </ul>  
    <section>
        <h1 class="outline">Shopping List Items</h1>
        <ul class="shopping_item_list">
            <li>Flowers<span class="delete">Delete</span></li>
            <li>A gift card for mom's birthday<span class="delete">Delete</span></li>
            <li>A birthday card<span class="delete">Delete</span></li>
            <li>Yogurt<span class="delete">Delete</span></li>
            <li>Applesauce<span class="delete">Delete</span></li>
            <li>Iced tea<span class="delete">Delete</span></li>
            <li>Ice cream<span class="delete">Delete</span></li>
            <li>Laundry detergent<span class="delete">Delete</span></li>
            <li>Sandwich bags<span class="delete">Delete</span></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div><!--end wrapper-->
```

CSS:

```
    .wrapper {
margin-left: 100px;
margin-right: 100px;
    }

   .lPadding { 
padding-left: 100px;
    }

   .rPadding {
padding-right: 100px;
    }

    input[name="shopping_item"], input[name="shopping_item"]:focus { 
margin-top: 50px;
width: 94.4%; 
padding-left: 2.8%;
padding-right: 2.8%;
border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
height: 91px;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow:none;
font-size: 24px;
}

   .shopping_item_list li {
background-color: #6ea24a;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
width: 25%;
min-height: 150px;
padding-top: 67px;
padding-left:2.5%;
padding-right:2.5%; 
padding-bottom: 25px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-left: 5%;
color: #fff;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
position: relative; /* To position Delete span */
}

   .shopping_item_list li:nth-child(1), .shopping_item_list li:nth-child(4),    
   .shopping_item_list li:nth-child(7) {
margin-left:0;
}


    .shopping_item_list li:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #ec5084;
}
```

Comment: you can use text-align:justify or the flex version justify-content:space-between; in a container of same width as input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `text-align` properties or `flex` properties :

**text-align properties:** **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ctrzf)**

```
.shopping_item_list {
  text-align:justify
}
.shopping_item_list:after {/*add an extra lineso  last line of element is justified too*/
  content:'';
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**flex properties**:**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ywuAf)**

```
.shopping_item_list {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

---

**Mind a reset on padding for ul, for both methods**

Comment: In the demo, the edge of the first box is not lined up with the edge of the input box. It's a little to the right.

Comment: @amylynn83 adjust width of container to width of input and mind the padding( such as ul{padding:0;}) and borders if any. no margins have to be set to lis as well :)

Comment: I tried the display:flex and I thought it was a great solution - until I removed a list item which then caused a row to have two squares, and then they were distributed across the entire row. Is there a way to keep them left justified?

Comment: @amylynn83 yes , add an extra element with same width but heigh:0; , it can be a pseudo. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LlbEx

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `li` elements be `float:left` and remove the margin/padding from the `ul` element

So add `.shopping_item_list{display:block;margin:0;padding:0;}` and `float:left` to the `.shopping_item_list li` rule.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ZxLHZ/2/

---

Another thing is that you can use `:nth-child(3n+1)` instead of `:nth-child(1), :nth-child(4), :nth-child(7)` etc..